# Delphi 10.1 doesn't find the units added with an installed package

Tags: delphi, ide

I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin Starter and have the following problem:

Is added some packages by opening them, and installing them by right-clicking on the package in the project manager and choosing "install". The compiled packages are now in the same folder as the other packages Delphi uses, so I think that there cannot be a problem with the library or search path.

The packages also added some Components that are now accessible in the tool palette. If I add one of these components to my program, Delphi automatically adds the unit name of the component to the "uses" section of the unit containing the component. But if I want to compile, Delphi throws the fatal error "could not find unit_name.pas".

How can I fix this? Does the units required to build and install the packages have to be included in a library path?

Maybe this is a compatibility problem. The packages were written in 2008 (Are Namespaces in Delphi younger?), so maybe the way the package wants to tell the compiler what to do does not work anymore.

This question might be difficult to understand (I had some problems to explain it...), so please comment, if you need more information.

Comment: Yes, it has to be in your library path. Did the component you installed not have installation instructions?

Comment: @KenWhite Does "it" mean the Units of the Package?

Comment: No. *It* is the folder where the units are located. (The path to the package's units.)

Comment: @KenWhite There were no installation instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy, I just had to add the units of the package to the library path (Tools->Options->Delphi Options->Library). Worked. Thanks to KenWhite.

Comment: This is really problematic, esp. when you have multiple platforms. Why can't Delphi treat packages at least in the same project group like libraries and set the paths as needed?